# Why doesn't my stackSize method work?

Tags: java, eclipse, stack-size

My objective is to provide a class Stacker that contains a method stackSize that takes an int called extension as its parameter.  It should return the smallest long n such that the sum of the sequence 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/6 + 1/8 + ... + ... + 1/2n is greater than or equal to extension.

Assuming my Rat class (Rational Number) correctly adds up two fractions using the first parameter as a numerator and the second parameter as a denominator, any ideas why this code isn't working for me?

The default Rat() constructor simply makes the Rational number (0/1) and the Rat(extension) constructor makes the Rational number (extension/1).

```
public class StackerTest {

@Test
public void test1()
{
    assertEquals(4, Stacker.stackSize(1));
}
```

}

When I run the test case:

```
@Test
    public void test1()
    {
        assertEquals(4, Stacker.stackSize(1));
    }
```

It runs for a solid 30 seconds before giving an IllegalArgumentException

Here is the constructor for Rat class as well as the add method

```
/**
     * If d is zero, throws an IllegalArgumentException. Otherwise creates the
     * rational number n/d
     */
    public Rat (int n, int d)
    {
        // Check parameter restriction
        if (d == 0)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        // Adjust sign of denominator
        num = n;
        den = d;
        if (den < 0)
        {
            num = -num;
            den = -den;
        }

        // Zero has a standard representation
        if (num == 0)
        {
            den = 1;
        }

        // Factor out common terms
        int g = gcd(Math.abs(num), den);
        num = num / g;
        den = den / g;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the sum of this and r
     */
    public Rat add (Rat r)
    {
        int firstNum = this.num*r.den;
        int firstDen = this.den*r.den;
        int secondNum = r.num*this.den;
        int secondDen = r.den*this.den;
        Rat x = new Rat(firstNum+secondNum, firstDen);
        return x;
    }
```

Comment: Can you paste your Rat constructor here, as well as the add method? The problem seems like it has to do with your Rat object, not the code you've pasted above. Additionally, was there anything else included with the exception message rather than just the exception type?

Comment: Please paste more code; `Rat` and `Stacker`. Also, can you test if the while loop condition is valid or causes infinite loop?